# Java using args and methods, how do i do this?

Tags: java, string

I enrolled in a Java course and I got an assignment where I am given five string args and I have to combine them to form the line " Java programming is easy as ABC!.

For this I was given the following code:

```
    public static String one(String arg){
        arg = arg + " Java";
        return arg;
    }

    public static String two(String arg){
        arg = arg + " easy as";
        return arg;
    }

    public static String three(String arg){

        arg = arg + "Programming";
        return arg;
    }

    public static String four(String arg){
        arg = arg + " is";
        return arg;
    }

    public static String five(String arg){
        arg = arg + " with";

        return arg;
    }

    public static String six(String arg){
        arg = arg + " ABC!";
        return arg;
    }

    @Test
    public void testVolgorde(){
        String arg = "";            
        Assert.assertEquals("Programming with Java is easy as ABC!", arg);
    }
```

}

Now I could assign a string to arg, but is there another way to do it? Via concatenation for example?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You just have to call each of the methods right?

Comment: Do you have to make " Java programming is easy as ABC!" as your question says, or "Programming with Java is easy as ABC!" as your assertion says?

Comment: The example above that your instructor gave you is kind of "cute" but isn't really a great way to start learning.  I'd be a little leery of this course.  Ask your instructor frequently for help, it's not your fault if you don't understand.  I don't know why you're using JUnit (the @Test method) in a starting program.

Comment: @user7 correct andmarkspace; he said i should not worry about it for now, but thanks for the warning

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is start from " " and in each call i add another word to that string. In the end you have the complete sentence in 'result':

```
String result = six(two(four(three(one("")))));
Assert.assertEquals("Programming with Java is easy as ABC!", result);
```

Comment: The idea is start from " " and in each call i add another word to that string.
In the end you have the complete sentence in 'result'

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The course try to tell you to write *one* method to combine several String.

When you have multiple arguments of the same type, you often wrap them to an array or a varargs arguments:

```
public String version1(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder ("");
    for (String arg : args) {
        output.append(arg); // concat them
    }
    return ouput.toString();
}

public String version2(String... args) {
     // Do the same thing as version 1
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder ("");
    for (String arg : args) {
        output.append(arg); // concat them
    }
    return ouput.toString();
}
```